# OutputResponse in V9 vs V10

Tags: differential-equations, bugs, control-systems

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and persisting through 10.2 or later**

---

I have same code that works in version 9.0.1, but not in version 10.0.1.0 (according to @Sektor, it works in 10.0.0.0, too).

```
in = UnitStep[t - 20] - UnitStep[t - 75];
tMax = 100;
time = {t, 0, tMax};

thisWc = TransferFunctionModel[{{{0.9 (1 + 19 s)}}, 19 s}, s]

Wp23 = TransferFunctionModel[{{{E^((-2) s)}}, (1 + 2 s)^5}, s]

out = OutputResponse[
  SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[
   SystemsModelSeriesConnect[thisWc, Wp23]], in, time]
```

One can approximate the TF in v10 with (thanks to @Nasser):

```
Wp23Approx = SystemsModelDelayApproximate[Wp23]

outApprox = 
 OutputResponse[
  SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[
   SystemsModelSeriesConnect[thisWc, Wp23Approx]], in, time]
```

Then the Error changes from

```
NestList::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in NestList[#1/. Control`RecastDEquationsDump`xx$_[t+Optional[Pattern[<<2>>]]]:>Control`RecastDEquationsDump`xx$[t+Control`RecastDEquationsDump`nn0$+1]&,Control`RecastDEquationsDump`y$615011[t]->Control`RecastDEquationsDump`stVar$6154[t]+Control`RecastDEquationsDump`cst$6156 Subscript[\[FormalU], 1][t],2.]. >> ....
```

to

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 20.00000000000057`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>
```

Surprisingly in v9 (and 10.0.0.0) both ways give the same result:
[image]

Edit:
I'm using Win7 64bit

Comment: I get the same error-free output executing this code @ 9.0.1.0 and @ 10.0.0.0. Try starting a clean kernel.

Comment: @Sektor Unfortunately, evaluating this code on a new (empty) notebook with new started kernel, I still get the errors. I'm using v10.0.1.0

Comment: What is your OS ? We should wait for others to confirm before filing a bug report.

Comment: I'm working with Mma 10.0.1.0 and Windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: I now found a v9.0.1 and as expected, I'll get the output.

Comment: Still, version 10.0.0.0 perfectly fine - I get the same plot

Comment: Doesn't work in 10.0.2 under Windows.  I vote for "bug."

Comment: This is a bug. The workaround for now is to convert thisWcA, Wp23, or the final system to a StateSpaceModel.

Comment: Seems to work again in 10.2

Answer (score 1):

You can get output if you first approximate your system. You have a delayed control system there due to the `E^(-2)` in the numerator of the wp23 transfer function. So use this below. In addition, asking for Minimal state model allows you to solve for this specific input you have

```
ClearAll[t, s];
in = 2 UnitStep[t - 20] - UnitStep[t - 500];
tMax = 100;
time = {t, 0, tMax};
wp23 = TransferFunctionModel[{{{E^((-2) s)}}, (1 + 2 s)^5}, s];
wp23 = SystemsModelDelayApproximate[wp23];
thisWcA = TransferFunctionModel[{{{0.8908858730832925 (1 + 19.096 s)}}, 19.096 s}, s];
tf = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[thisWcA, wp23];
tf = SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[tf];
ss = MinimalStateSpaceModel@StateSpaceModel@tf;
out = First@OutputResponse[ss, in, time];
Plot[out /. t -> i, {i, 0, tMax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

See [DelayControlSystems.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DelayControlSystems.html)  for more information on delay control systems and [SystemsModelDelayApproximate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelDelayApproximate.html?q=SystemsModelDelayApproximate)

Comment: Ok, well, but in this old notebook I could evaluate exactly this code. Even with this input. @Sektor could do an error-free executing of this code, too.

Comment: @Phab In version 10, your code produces error. The above fix removes the error. I do not know why it worked in version 9. May be they fixed something and it should not have worked in V 9. I do not know. You asked to make it work in V10.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. But what could i do with this workaround, if I can't see it with the input signal I want? ... but v9 does.

Comment: @Phab as I said, with your specific input, the delayed unit step, the error is not related to the invalid TF. It is due to system being stiff with this specific input. The error now is `At t == 20.00000000000057, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>` So this is a separate issue, not related to original error about invalid TF. There can be other work around this now. But I did it pursue this, since I do not think it is related to your original error.

Comment: I tried to get a response of the approximated TF in v9, there it works fine. So your answer pushed my problem one step further, but didn't solve it. ... I'll edit the question acordingly.